# How to correctly type return values in child class (typescript)

Tags: typescript, types

I want to create a base class for working with API (let's call it `BaseAPI`). Then, for each API, create a wrapper like `UsersAPI`, `LoginAPI` and such. So base class only encapsulates logic for making HTTP requests and aligning responses to same structure.

Minimal example:

```js
type BaseResp = Record<string, unknown>

class BaseAPI {
    async get(url: string): Promise<BaseResp> {
        const resp = await fetch(url)
        return await resp.json()
    }
}

interface LoginResp extends BaseResp {
    username: string
}

class AuthAPI extends BaseAPI {
    async login(): Promise<LoginResp> {
        return await this.get("/login")
    }
}
```

The problem is that in fact `BaseApi.get` returns a `Promise<any>`, cause I don't know what data comes from the backend, so it's `any`.

But I know how server responds to `/login` API calls, so I want to receive typed object (`LoginResp`) after awaiting `AuthAPI.login`.

My linter is set up the way that it doesn't allow `any` usage, and I don't want to suppress it.
That's why I tried to follow TS conventions and replace `any` with `Record<string, unknown>`.

Now I'm getting an error: `Property 'username' is missing in type 'Promise<BaseResp>' but required in type 'LoginResp'.(2741)`

How to set up typing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result of json raw parsing will always be `any` (type of it cannot be determined at compile time) you have 2 choices.

**1. You trust what comes back from the server.**

In this case you can cast the parsed json data, you could modify your `BaseApi` type to something like this:

```
class BaseAPI {
    async get<T extends BaseResp>(url: string): Promise<T> {
        const resp = await fetch(url)
        return await resp.json() as T
    }
}
```

**2. You don't trust what's coming back from the server**

In this case you could set up type guards:

```
function isLoginResp(input: any): input is LoginResp {
  return typeof input === 'object' && typeof input.username === 'string'
}
```

And while keeping the rest of your code as is, you could change your `AuthApi` class:

```
class AuthAPI extends BaseAPI {
    async login(): Promise<LoginResp> {
        const response = await this.get("/login")
        if (isLoginResp(response)) {
          return response
        }
        throw new TypeError(`Expected LoginResp, got ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering, at least I've tried the first option and it worked. Could you explain what `get<T extends BaseResp>` notation means? Or at least how it's called so I can read the documentation?

Comment: @fbjorn sure, here you can read more about it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints . In this case what it means that your function will have a generic parameter `T`, and that `T` type has a constraint on it, so that it should have at least the properties of `BaseResp`. When you call your function you could also call it like this: `this.get<LoginResp>(...)` to be more accurate, but the type is inferred anyways.